# std::vector element error that i dont understand

Tags: c++, templates, vector

im trying to make a function to serialize a class in my own way. i was using a template struck to hold every form of a primitive variable. im getting an error in my serializing function. i dont want my element to be static in my stuct b/c i want to hold many different random element please help!

```
struct _PVS
{
public:
    template<typename _PV> _PVS(_PV &PV)
        : ele(PV)
    {}
    template<typename _PV> _PV ele;
};
class player_one {

    std::vector<_PVS*> serializing;

    const string PL_name = "JOHN!";
    unsigned short int hp = 100;
    unsigned short int shield = 55;
    string fav_food = "soup.";

public:

    player_one() {

        serializing.push_back(new _PVS(PL_name));
        serializing.push_back(new _PVS(hp));
        serializing.push_back(new _PVS(shield));
        serializing.push_back(new _PVS(fav_food));

    }

    void serialclass() {
        ofstream _F;
        string temp;
        _F.open("player_one.log");

        for (int i = 0; i < serializing.size(); i++) {
        temp = (std::string)serializing[i].ele;
            //getline to pass in whole lines for data for serializing
        }



    };

};
```

Comment: You can't have non-static template member variables.

Comment: then is there anyway to make a vector hold an int string bool etc without any given order that can changed often

Comment: I don't like this idea too much, but what you could do is to make `_PVS` polymorphic (and probably abstract), then derive a template class from it (`template <typename T> struct foo : _PVS {...};`). Keep the vector of pointers to `_PVS`, but make it point to instances of that derived template.

Comment: Also, names starting with `_` followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation and shouldn't be used (same as names containing `__`).

Comment: alright ill try this but wait if u dont like the idea what would you do?

Comment: What you're trying to do is basically called *reflection*. Look up some reflection libraries, maybe you could use them instead (or at least learn some nice tricks from them).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you so much!!! time to start the grind

Comment: Generally, serialization should encode type information and data in a consistent manner that produces a single type of its own at run time. It's much cleaner that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Binary Serialization

Below is a sample of how you might approach serialization for a low-level file format. Note that we only know how to serialize two field types (`uint16_t` and `std::string`). You could specialize additional types as needed.

### Data Format

The first thing we want to do is pick a data format. I've used a simple block-based approach below, where we have two bytes reserved for the type and length of each field. Whenever you want to serialize a field, you first write a number that represents the type and then a number indicating how many bytes follow the header.

This is known as a variable-length encoding.

### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

enum class SerializedType {
    Unknown,
    UnsignedShortInteger,
    String
};
struct mapInt {
public:
    const uint8_t first;
    const uint8_t second;
    mapInt(uint16_t value)
    : first((value & 0xff00)>>8),
      second(value & 0xff) {
    }
};

std::vector<uint8_t> toWireFormat(const uint16_t& value) {
    const auto mapped = mapInt(value);
    const std::vector<uint8_t> data = {
        static_cast<uint8_t>(SerializedType::UnsignedShortInteger),
        2,
        mapped.first,
        mapped.second
    };
    return data;
}

std::vector<uint8_t> toWireFormat(const std::string& value) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
    data.resize(value.size() + 2);
    data[0] = static_cast<uint8_t>(SerializedType::String);
    data[1] = static_cast<uint8_t>(value.size());
    for (auto i = 0; i < value.size(); ++i) {
        data[i+2] = value.at(i);
    }
    return data;
}

std::string serializedTypeAsString(SerializedType type) {
    switch (type) {
        case SerializedType::Unknown:
            return " Unknown";
        case SerializedType::UnsignedShortInteger:
            return "uint16_t";
        case SerializedType::String:
            return "  string";
    }
}

template<class T>
void appendData(std::vector<uint8_t>& data, const T& value) {
    const auto buffer = toWireFormat(value);
    data.insert(data.end(), buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
}

class PlayerOne {
public:
    const string name;
    uint16_t hp;
    uint16_t shield;
    string favFood = "soup";

    PlayerOne() = default;
    ~PlayerOne() = default;

    void serialize(std::vector<uint8_t>& data) const {
        appendData(data, name);
        appendData(data, hp);
        appendData(data, shield);
        appendData(data, favFood);
    };
};

int main()
{
   PlayerOne ready = { "JOHN!", 100, 55, "Soup" };
   PlayerOne two = { "Sarah", 250, 0, "Cake" };

    vector<uint8_t> output;
    ready.serialize(output);
    two.serialize(output);

    cout << "Serialized two objects into " << output.size() << " bytes." << endl;
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < output.size()) {
        const auto typeString = serializedTypeAsString(
            static_cast<SerializedType>(output.at(i)));
        const int length = output.at(i+1);
        cout << "\nType: " << typeString << ", Length: " << length << ", Data: ";
        i += 2;
        if ((i+length) > output.size()) {
            break;
        }
        for (size_t j = i; j < (i+length); ++j) {
            cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << static_cast<int>(output.at(j));
        }
        i += length;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Sample Output

Note: The strings below are encoded in hexadecimal format. The strings are not null-terminated to save space in the binary format. You'd have to re-apply null byte terminators when de-serializing.

```
Serialized two objects into 42 bytes.

Type:   string, Length: 5, Data: 4a4f484e21
Type: uint16_t, Length: 2, Data: 0064
Type: uint16_t, Length: 2, Data: 0037
Type:   string, Length: 4, Data: 536f7570
Type:   string, Length: 5, Data: 5361726168
Type: uint16_t, Length: 2, Data: 00fa
Type: uint16_t, Length: 2, Data: 0000
Type:   string, Length: 4, Data: 43616b65
```